# Can I store more than 5 MB in HTML5 local(offline) storage?

Tags: html, storage, local-storage, offline

Can I store more than 5 MB in HTML5 local(offline) storage?
I referred  the following sources,

1. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
2. http://htmlui.com/blog/2011-08-23-5-obscure-facts-about-html5-localstorage.html

and they say no.But they are over an year old  and newer versions of Chrome and safari has been released since then.

I am concerned only about  chrome and safari.My web app is expected to run on tablets and laptops.
A clear answer is highly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values

Comment: @RTB The question is older than the asker's sources.

Comment: The test page that one of the answers to the linked page, however, is useful: http://arty.name/localstorage.html

Comment: Happily, 2+ years later the answer "usually 5MB" still seems to be correct for most common cases.

Comment: No. 2.5M for localStorage and 2.5MB for sessionStorage. it is not design to store large data because it is non-transactional synchronous API.